# Where should I use act when testing an async react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hooks-testing-library

When testing an async react hook with `@testing-library/react-hooks` I see an error message.  The error message mentions wrapping code in `act(...)` but I'm not sure where I should do this.

I have tried to wrap parts of the code in `act(...)` but each attempt leads to the test failing.

```
// day.js 
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getDay } from '../api/day';

export function useDay() {
  const [state, set] = useState({ loading: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    let canSet = true;

    set({ loading: true });
    const setDay = async () => {
      const day = await getDay();
      if (canSet) {
        set(day);
      }
    };

    setDay();

    return () => (canSet = false);
  }, []);

  return state;
}
```

```
// day.test.js
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { useDay } from "./day";

jest.mock("../api/day", () => ({
  getDay: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ some: "value" })
}));

describe.only("model/day", () => {
  it("returns data", async () => {
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useDay());
    await waitForNextUpdate();
    expect(result.current).toEqual({ some: "value" });
  });
});
```

```
// test output
console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:102
      Warning: An update to TestHook inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue:  https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/281

Before `16.9.0-alpha.0` React itself didn't handle the async stuff pretty good, so that has nothing to do with the testing library, really. Read the comments of the issue if you're interested in that.

You have two options now:

1. Update your React (& `react-dom`) to `16.9.0-alpha.0`
2. Add a snippet (e. g. in your test setup file) to suppress that warning when `console.log` tries to print it:

---

```
// FIXME Remove when we upgrade to React >= 16.9
const originalConsoleError = console.error;
console.error = (...args) => {
  if (/Warning.*not wrapped in act/.test(args[0])) {
    return;
  }
  originalConsoleError(...args);
};
```

Comment: 16.9.0 has been released now and `waitForNextUpdate` has been updated to automatically handle the async `act` call.  Updating to the latest version should make the warning go away.